# "LPVOID" can not be assigned to an entity of the type X

Tags: c++, heapalloc

I am dealing with a function that deals with USB devices.

But I am already having a problem at something simple:

I am getting the compiler error

```
A value of the type "LPVOID" can not be assigned to an entity of the type "PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA" in the line 
"DevIntfDetailData = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize);"
```

Could anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you!

```
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA DevIntfDetailData;
DevIntfDetailData = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize);
```

Comment: C++ requires casting for this (C does not).

Comment: DevIntfDetailData = reinterpret_cast<PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA>(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize)); - have to work

Comment: @Arkady Thanks a lot! Can you make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That have to work:

```
DevIntfDetailData = reinterpret_cast<PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA>(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize));
```

HealAlloc (like all other alloc function)  returns pointer to memory heap (void*), and C++ can't allow set value of type T* to value of type void* without manual casting.

There exist dynamic_cast, static_cast, reinterpret_cast and const_cast. When you want to convert void* to any pointer, you have to use reinterpret_cast, because it converts types without any checking (converting void* to any T* will not pass any check).